# MVC 4 Setting Active Item on Menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following menu defined in my _Layout.cshtml, which is shared across all my pages in my site

```
<ul id="topnav" class="sf-menu">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = Html.ActivePage("Home", "Index") })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Services", "Services", "Home", null, new { @class = Html.ActivePage("Home", "Services") })
        <ul>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("1", "1", "Services", null, new { @class = Html.ActivePage("Home", "Services") })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("2", "2", "Services", null, new { @class = Html.ActivePage("Home", "Services") })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("3", "3", "Services", null, new { @class = Html.ActivePage("Home", "Services") })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("3", "4", "Services", null, new { @class = Html.ActivePage("Home", "Services") })</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("FAQs", "FAQs", "Home", null, new { @class = Html.ActivePage("Home", "FAQs") })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", null, new { @class = Html.ActivePage("Home", "About") })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home", null, new { @class = Html.ActivePage("Home", "Contact") })</li>
</ul>
```

My RouteConfig is as follows

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Home",
    url: "{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Services",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Services", action = "Index" }
);
```

and my HTMLHelper is defined as follows

```
public static string ActivePage(this HtmlHelper helper, string controller, string action)
{
    string classvalue = "";
    string currentController = helper.ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue.ToString();
    string currentAction = helper.ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString();
    if (currentController == controller && currentAction == action)
        classvalue = "active";
    return classvalue;
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is when a user selects any of the subitems of the 'Services' menu that the 'Services' menu item is marked as 'Active'.  The code is functioning as is when I select the top-level menu items but not the child items.

Can anyone offer any suggestions on this.

TIA
Trevor Lewis.

Comment: Show us the CSS styles. Also what do you mean by "The code is functioning as is when I select the top-level menu items but not the child items." Can you provide examples?

Comment: I i select the 'Services' item, i.e. the Parent item then the LI is marked with the 'active' css class as intended.   However if I select for example the child item '1' of the 'Services' menu I would like the parent item e.g 'Services' marked with the 'active' class.   The CSS is functioning its just the MVC code to find the parent menu item and mark that as 'active' thats missing.